# Generate column list in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've cooked up the following SQL to generate the `select` portion of a query that, given a table, lists all columns in said table:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
set @cols = '';

SELECT @cols += lower(', ' + c.name)
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tablename')

select RIGHT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 2);

-- output:
-- id, sex, isactive, displayname ...
```

Is there a better way to do this? Are there any tools that can perform this task quickly?

I'm trying to prevent having to write out a bunch of column names. Would much rather generate a list, as described in the code snippet, and remove columns I'm not going to need.

Comment: In SSMS, You can also right click on table and choose: **Script Table As** - **Select to** - **New query editor window**

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can drag and drop the Columns folder into any Query window which gives you those same results quickly (though not programmatically of course).

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 that's cool, but i don't like mice and the click-n-drag bit. looking for a more intelligent method. maybe a third-party tool, macro, or some other amalgamation.

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
select stuff((SELECT  lower(' ,' + c.name)
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('<<TABLENAME>>')
for xml path('')),1,2,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
@cols =stuff((SELECT  ', ' + c1.name FROM sys.columns c1 where c.object_id=c1.object_id for xml path('')),1,1,'')
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tablename')

select @cols
```